# PHP - Error 500 after page refresh

Tags: php, session, serialization

I've got a PHP application and I'm having trouble getting a User object from the SESSION.

When saving the object I have the following code (some other file).

```
$_SESSION['user'] = serialize($user);
```

The problem begins when I try and load a file called timeline.php. The first time I load the page (after I've logged in and the SESSION['user] is set) the page works fine. When I refresh the page I get an error 500.

The error log shows this:

Call to a member function get() on a non-object in timeline.php on line 10.

The code from line 2-10 is this:

```
include_once('isUserLoggedIn.php');
require_once('classes/User.php');

session_start();

$user = unserialize($_SESSION['user']);

require_once('classes/Database.php');
$tweets = Database::getTimeline($user->get('user_id'));
```

Can anyone offer any reason for this?

*UPDATE (1)*

In timeline.php I added var_dump($user) to line 8. The first time I load the page it gives me the correct value.

The second time I load the page it gives me bool(false).

*UPDATE (2)*

The problem seems to be with the host (perhaps a setting in the php.ini file there). The company I was using is Fatcow. When I used someone elses host (1and1) the issue didn't happen.

Comment: $user is not an object. Add var_dump($user); on line 8 of timeline.php. Also, if you already have a session started, you should wrap your session_start in a conditional. if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}

Comment: Did that. The first time I load the page it shows me                                  object(User)#1 (11) { ["user_id"]=> int(1) ["email_address"]=> string(18) "rag4real@gmail.com" ["username"]=> string(13) "richardgorman" ["forename"]=> string(7) "richard" ["surname"]=> string(6) "gorman" ["avatar"]=> string(26) "images/avatars/default.jpg" ["website"]=> NULL ["bio"]=> string(25) "I'll fill this out later." ["postcount"]=> int(0) ["followercount"]=> int(0) ["followingcount"]=> int(0) }

Comment: When I refreshed the page it showed bool(false).

Comment: Do you have cookies disabled? Have you checked for anomalies in 'isUserLoggedIn.php' and 'classes/User.php'?

Comment: They seem to be fine. This whole application works fine locally I should add.

Answer (score 0):

When unserializing objects lots of strange things can occur, see the PHP manual page for more information.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

This comment seems pertinent:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php#77826

Comment: Your other alternative is to just save the User ID and then rebuild their user class (if you're using an ORM then it's just a case of running the query on that ID). Or evaluate what you need the user class for, just data? Then stick that data in the session as an array and be done with it.